# How to add third party script?

Tags: amp-html

I want to add leadpages embed script to amp HTML page, here my script

```
<script src="https://static.leadpages.net/leadboxes/current/embed.js" async></script>
```

Let me know how we add this script.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `<script>` tags are not allowed in AMP.

However you can use `<amp-script>` tag to load custom javascript with limited functionality. 
You can read about it [here](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript/).

Comment: I have already tried this but embed script not working and in console getting the error: Remove unused script.